# Opening a new ViewController from a UITableView in a tabbed app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

**Introduction**

So I created a new tabbed app in xcode and created a new ViewController with nib set up etc... I then created a TableView in that ViewController from an array of strings. Everything is fine t'ill here. Then I want a new ViewController to open when a cell is tapped and pass the title of the cell (i.e. the string in the array) to that new ViewController. So I wrote some code, created a new ViewController added the nib to storyboard and connected it to its class (and gave it the correct storyboard id). But for some reason the view doesn't load up when I tap a cell. I can't figure out why.. Do I need to do some additional set up in storyboard? add a navigationController or something?

**My Code**

```
#import "CreationViewController.h"

@interface CreationViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *templateList;

@end

@implementation CreationViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.templateList =  tempList;
    // tempList is defined by some code I removed but that's working fine
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.templateList count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    NSString *tweet = [self.templateList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.templateList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TemplateViewController *dvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TemplateViewController"];
    dvc.tweet = [self.templateList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: You should add a UINavigationController and embed the new view on it. Try it, it should work. I mean, in your storyboard, with new view selected, click in the option "embed view in a navigation controller". Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! been pulling out my hair for an hour

Comment: I know, sometimes the behavior of iOS is funny, believe me :) glad to help :)